# Reading specific lines in a file

Tags: java, jframe, filereader

Hard to explain the problem, but ill try my best. Basically i want the program to read lines 1-6 of a text file, then read lines 7-12, then 13-18. but right now its not.

My output is this:

[First run](http://puu.sh/7QbaS/6c51ad9ee4.jpg)

[Second run](http://puu.sh/7QbCB/0a88e281b8.jpg)

Ignore the number in the top left, that was just so i could test my lock in button.

I have no idea what to do. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Game extends JFrame
{
JLabel lblQuestion;
JRadioButton btA;
JRadioButton btB;
JRadioButton btC;
JRadioButton btD;
JButton btLock;
JTextField txtQuestion;
int question = 0;

public Game()
{
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setupGUI();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

.

```
    btLock.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btLock.setEnabled(false);
            btLock.setText("Lock In");
            txtQuestion.setText(Integer.toString(question));
            try{
                String[] array = questions();
                lblQuestion.setText("<html>"+array[0]+"</html>");
                btA.setText(array[1]);
                btB.setText(array[2]);
                btC.setText(array[3]);
                btD.setText(array[4]);
            }catch(Exception ex){}



            question++;
        }
    });

    setTitle("Who wants to be a millionare");
    setSize(570,400);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);


}

public String[] questions() throws IOException{
    File file = new File("questions.txt");
    if (!file.exists()){
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find \"users\" file");
    }
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String[] array = new String[6];

    //I wanted this to skip the lines i dont need but i didnt work
    for(int i = 0; (i*5) < question; i++){
        br.readLine();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        array[i] = br.readLine();
    }

    br.close();
    return array;   
}

public static void main( String args[] )
{
    new Game();
}
}
```

Comment: First, determine everything in your code that is unrelated to the problem. Then **take it out** from your post. It's noise.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry, didn't notice how much junk i actually posted

Comment: Now, the reading file part doesn't really have anything to do with the GUI, so create a dedicated method that just does the file reading. Use a debugger to see what you are reading and what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Im an idiot

```
for(int i = 0; i < question; i++){
        br.readLine();
        br.readLine();
        br.readLine();
        br.readLine();
        br.readLine();
        br.readLine();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        array[i] = br.readLine();
    }
```

Done